# Replace for loop to increase speed of my python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python so be gentle. I want to map values of a numpy.ndarray called "image" to other values that I store in a numpy.ndarray called "maps".

I have the following short script to do this (in my script image is obviously not just zeros):

```
import numpy as np
import time

maps = np.arange(1024)
image = np.zeros((3800,2560))
t0 = time.time()
for ii in range(len(maps)):
    image[image == ii] = maps[ii]
print('time = ' + str(np.round(time.time()-t0,3)))
```

Result:

```
time = 6.167
```

It does what I want but in my code I need this many times and long story short, it runs very slow (usually around ~6 seconds per call).
Is there any straight forward way to improve the speed of this? :)
I know that generally using for loops is the worst but I can't think of a way around it.

I am using python 3.7.6

Thanks a lot for your patience and help. 
Let me know if there is anything else I forgot to mention that might help you find a solution.

Markus

EDIT

It seems like my first example was too generic, so I show something here that is closer to what I do:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a=1.5
points = np.array([[-np.pi,-np.pi/a]
,[-2.0,-2/a]
,[0,0]
,[2.0,2/a]
,[np.pi,np.pi/a],])
# fit spline
spline = interp1d(points[:,0], points[:,1], kind='cubic')

colormap_values = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,(2**10), endpoint=True)
colormap = spline(colormap_values)
np.place(colormap, colormap>np.pi, np.pi)
np.place(colormap, colormap<-np.pi, -np.pi)
maps = np.floor((1023)*(colormap+np.pi)/(2*np.pi))

im = np.random.randint(0,1023,size = (3800,2560))
image = im.astype('f')

t0 = time.time()
for ii in range(len(maps)):
    image[image == ii] = maps[ii]
print('time = ' + str(np.round(time.time()-t0,3)))
```

Result:

```
time = 6.547
```

Comment: `image[image == ii] = maps[ii]`? Is this *really* what you want, to only set `image[True]` and `image[False]`? Not *entirely* certain what you're trying to acheive there.

Comment: Your first pass through the loop will replace all of the zeroes with zeroes since ii is zero and mask[ii] is also zero.  All subsequent passes will replace none of the values in image (which are still all zeroes) because ii is then > 0 and it doesn't matter what mask[ii] is at that point.  Perhaps you could find a better example and also provide a sample of the expected result.  As things stand, the best optimization would be to remove the for loop completely.  You will get the same result by doing nothing (which is faster than anything)

Comment: I update my question to be a bit more specific to my actual code. Apologies for the confusion, I just quickly made up a generic example that is easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, for this specific example you can go with

```
result = maps[image]
```

More generally, you can use `scipy.ndimage.labelled_comprehension`:

```
from scipy.ndimage import labeled_comprehension
result = labeled_comprehension(
    image, None, None, maps.__getitem__, out_dtype=np.int, default=0
    ).reshape(image.shape)
```

This runs in 17ms on my machine, as opposed to 11.5s for the original code.

Note that `labelled_comprehension` ignores zero labels. If `maps[0] != 0`, you may need to increment every element of the original array and adjust the `maps` accordingly.

Comment: I am really sorry for not being more specific: in the code I am actually using, image is not full of zeros but other values. I have changed the code above to be closer to what I want.

Comment: No worries, that was a reasonable thing to assume. If you find yourself posing a similar question in the future, you could provide a random matrix as a placeholder for `image` with `np.random.seed(0)` as a way of getting a compact, reproducible and general example.

Comment: I updated the example to be closer to my actual code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that `res = maps[image.astype(np.int)]` still works. I am not sure why you included the `image = im.astype('f')` line, since the image is presumably given by an array of integers. If you delete the `image = im.astype('f')` line, `res = maps[image]` should work in place of the `for` loop. So, you could use `image = maps[image]`.

Comment: I deleted the 'image = im.astype('f')', that was from a previous test run. I just tried your suggestion but if I then subtract (image - result) , e.g. the result from the for loop minus the result from your suggestion, it should be 0 everywhere if it did the same thing, but it isn't

Comment: I do seem to get identical results. Note that your code modifies `image` inplace, so `image` is changed after the for loop is run. You could place `res = maps[image]` before the `for` loop and test for equality with `(image == res).all()`  after the for loop. Let me know if this resolves the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

@hilberts_drinking_problem , here is a quick example for a much smaller space to see what is going on:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a=1.5
points = np.array([[-np.pi,-np.pi/a]
    ,[-2.0,-2/a]
    ,[0,0]
    ,[2.0,2/a]
    ,[np.pi,np.pi/a],])
# fit spline
spline = interp1d(points[:,0], points[:,1], kind='cubic')


colormap_values = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,(2**10), endpoint=True)
colormap = spline(colormap_values)
np.place(colormap, colormap>np.pi, np.pi)
np.place(colormap, colormap<-np.pi, -np.pi)
maps = np.floor((1023)*(colormap+np.pi)/(2*np.pi))
maps =  maps.astype('int32')

# im = np.random.randint(0,1023,size = (3800,2560))
image = np.random.randint(0,1023,size = (5,3))
image1 = im

t0 = time.time()
for ii in range(len(maps)):
    image[image == ii] = maps[ii]
print('time = ' + str(np.round(time.time()-t0,3)))

t1 = time.time()
result = maps[im]
print('time2 = ' + str(np.round(time.time()-t1,3)))

print((image))
print((result))
```

Result:

```
time = 0.002
time2 = 0.0
[[509 543 509]
 [509 733 509]
 [651 723 509]
 [509 787 509]
 [509 603 509]]
[[372 618 705]
 [425 321 282]
 [773 483 510]
 [204 733 633]
 [812 596 720]]
```

So the two things are not doing the same. E.g. result[0,2] is not the same as image[0,2]. But looking at it in more detail it seems like what my code is doing is also incorrect. I will need to revisit. :)
Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that `image1 = im` does not create a copy. Try replacing `image1 = im` with `image1 = image.copy()` as well as `result = maps[im]` with `result = maps[image1]`.